# having issue while uploading An error occured in the upload. Please try again later

Tags: images, uploads

First there are lots of question with this title. I have went through all but any of this not solving my issue.
I am having error while uploading image on the server

Things i have tried

upload directory permissions are 777.

I tried to disable all plugins and tried to upload but the having same issue

```
{"success":true,"data":{"id":805,"title":"fig2_full","filename":"fig2_full-9.jpg","url":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/fig2_full-9.jpg","link":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/?attachment_id=805","alt":"","author":"1","description":"","caption":"Credit: \"Gemini Observatory Artwork by Lynette Cook\"\rArtist's conception of the multiple planet system, initially discovered with Gemini North adaptive optics images.","name":"fig2_full-12","status":"inherit","uploadedTo":804,"date":1568367804000,"modified":1568367804000,"menuOrder":0,"mime":"image\/jpeg","type":"image","subtype":"jpeg","icon":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-includes\/images\/media\/default.png","dateFormatted":"September 13, 2019","nonces":{"update":"e79baa8268","delete":"7317ad662a","edit":"35b4b31ef2"},"editLink":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-admin\/post.php?post=805&action=edit","meta":false,"authorName":"admin_dev","uploadedToLink":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-admin\/post.php?post=804&action=edit","uploadedToTitle":"Auto Draft","filesizeInBytes":2442286,"filesizeHumanReadable":"2 MB","context":"","height":1860,"width":2652,"orientation":"landscape","sizes":{"thumbnail":{"height":150,"width":150,"url":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/fig2_full-9-150x150.jpg","orientation":"landscape"},"medium":{"height":210,"width":300,"url":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/fig2_full-9-300x210.jpg","orientation":"landscape"},"large":{"height":718,"width":1024,"url":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/fig2_full-9-1024x718.jpg","orientation":"landscape"},"full":{"url":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/fig2_full-9.jpg","height":1860,"width":2652,"orientation":"landscape"}},"compat":{"item":"","meta":""}}}
```

Having this response while i checked on the network tab on developers console

Actually file is uploading but still it is showing this error... when I refresh the page and check the images shows.

attaching image for the reference there is broken response in the async-upload.php

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.